# Get active branch on git from date

Tags: git

How can I find out the branch that was checked-out on git on a specific date-time, if this is possible at all? I know I can get the commit at a date-time on a branch but I need to know if it was on that branch

Comment: That's not possible with git itself. Why do you want to know that/what are you _acually_ trying to do?

Comment: It appears you have a misunderstanding at the basis of your question.  Many branches can be simultaneously checked out at any one time, from any one repository.   If you have found that there was a commit at a particular time on a particular branch, then by definition the commit was on that branch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a local repository you can use `git reflog` to show a history of all branch changes and commits on that local repository. This way you can track what branch **you** did any commit on.

However if others did their commits on their local repositories, (and pushed their work to some other repository like github,) it is no longer possible for you to answer this question.

A "branch" in git is just a single commit with all its history, up to the very first commit of the repository. And it is very common for different branches to share much of their history. Therefore old commits are usually part of all branches.

If you simply want to know if a given commit is contained in a given branch you can use `git branch --contains <commit> <branch>`.

---

```
          /-a--a--a <-- branch1
x--x--x--x
          \-b--b--b <-- branch2
```

In the above example

- all the `a` commits are part of branch1
- all the `b` commits are part of branch2
- all the `x` commits are part of both branches

There is no way to tell how the branch was called at the time the `x` commits where created. You can rename branch names add additional names and delete branch names, and all of this will not leave any traces in history.

Git is really only about commits and their history not about branches and their names.

Answer (score 0):

You might already be happy with the `--decorate` option to `git log`.

If you need more leverage, you can add a little `branch --contains`. I just concocted this one-liner<sup>1</sup>:

```
for sha in $(git rev-list --all -1 --since=2013-12-23 --until=2014-01-01); do git log --decorate -1 "$sha"; git branch -a --contains "$sha"; done
```

Breaking it down:

```
for sha in $(git rev-list --all -1 --since=2013-12-23 --until=2014-01-01)
do 
    git log --decorate -1 "$sha"
    git branch -a --contains "$sha"
done
```

It would print something like

```
commit ebb4186a95fd210afdc31b490bbf6279a798d61a
Author: Seth Heeren <sgheeren@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 25 02:50:59 2013 +0100

    fixing compilation issue
* master
  remotes/bitbucket/HEAD -> bitbucket/master
  remotes/bitbucket/master
```

This means the last commit from the last 8 days in 2013, followed by a list of the branches that contain it (in this case, 3 branches, including `master` which is marked as the *current branch).

---

<sup>1</sup> git rev-list is *basically* the plumbing variant of `git log`. Tweak it to your particular query:

```
--all              select from all HEADs (following the parents)
--since/--until    this would be your date criteria
-1                 limit to a single commit
```

Depending on the funky-ness of your revision graph and/or defaults you might want to add `--date-order` too.